# How to convert string to jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I convert this string to jsx? I want this string to appear as an HTML element.

```
this.setState({
    input: "<h1 id="heading">Heading</h1> <h2 id="sub-heading">Sub-heading</h2> <h3 id="another-deeper-heading">Another deeper heading</h3>"
});

render() {
    return <div>{this.state.input}</div>
}
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to quote HTML elements in JSX, but an HTML element can only have one parent.  Get rid of the quotes, and move the div up to the variable, and you'll be all set.

So:

```
this.setState({
   input: <div><h1 id="heading">Heading</h1> <h2 id="sub-heading">Sub-heading</h2> <h3 id="another-deeper-heading">Another deeper heading</h3></div>
});

render() {
    return this.state.input
}
```

I'm not sure what you gain from this, though.  Best practice would be to keep simple data in `props` and `state`, and put the HTML wrapper in the render function, not in `state`.

Comment: The response that I get is a string with html elements in it. I have stored that data in the state and finaly I am trying to render that string as jsx but what I get in result is instead of Heading i got <h1>Heading</h1>.

Comment: @Bernardo then your only option is to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: @naomik  thank you dangerouslySetInnerHTML solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight the solution, the comment by @user633183:

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

[Documentation link](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)